# how to get mime type by magic numbers with flutter mime package

Tags: flutter, mime-types, mime, file-type

I failed to send a video file with an extension mp4 to backend because backend detected it as a bin file as the mime type return as `application/octet-stream` when backend checking the mime type.

I do have check the mime type with `lookupMimeType` that from Flutter package before sending to backend but `video/mp4` is the result that returned.

I tried with some online [tool](https://www.htmlstrip.com/mime-file-type-checker) to check the video file, its return me `application/octet-stream` [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYuey.png)

so I try dig deeper and found out that magic-numbers can be use to check mime type [here](https://pub.dev/documentation/mime/latest/mime/lookupMimeType.html)

so how can I achieve that?

*unfortunately I cant attach the video file here*